# Nesting navigators in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nested, react-navigation

I'm a beginner to react and find it difficult to understand exactly how react navigation works. Am I supposed to write all the navigation code in App.js or is it possible to nest in different screens (home.js etc).

**Simply put:**

- Can I make a stack navigator under App.js that refers to a stack screen of "home.js" that contains a button in its .js file - which in turn navigates to "settings.js" with an onPress event, or am I all wrong here?

**NEW EDIT:**

**Under App.js:**

```
 function HomeNavigator() {
  return(
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
        <HomeStack.Screen 
        name="home" 
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}/>
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  )
}


export default function App() {
  return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <HomeNavigator/>
</NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

**And then under home.js:**

```
function Home({navigation}) {
    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.center}>
        <Image style={styles.icon} source={require("../assets/logo_01.png")}/>
        <AppButton title="Create room" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("Settings")}/>         
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Thank you  in advance I'm going crazy trying to understand how it works

Comment: I edited my answer that answer your edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT for edited question**:

You need to declare a screen in your `HomeStack` and pass to it a component to render as a setting screen, see below:

```
function SettingsScreen() {
  return(
    <Text>You are on Settings Screen</Text>
  )
}

function HomeNavigator() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name='Home'
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false, //example of options
        }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='Settings' component={SettingsScreen} /> //You need to declare your screen name and pass to it a component
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

---

**Explanation for nested navigators**

You can nest navigators. You can go for something like this:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeNavigator() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name='Home'
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false, //example of options
        }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen name='Settings' component={SettingsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
      <RootStack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeNavigator} />
      //other screens/navigator if you need
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <RootNavigator />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

Nested navigators documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/)

To navigate from `HomeScreen` :

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}>
      <Text>Go to Settings</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Documentation to navigate to a new screen [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#navigating-to-a-new-screen)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand more but if I'm in my "HomeScreen.js" and have a button-component in there that should take me to settings, it gives me the error "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Settings"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Settings'?

Comment: @Ollie Can you update your question and add more details, with your code please ? So I can see where it's wrong ?

Comment: yes I added the code now, thank you for helping me! Is it more clear now or am I just completely not understanding this haha

Comment: @Ollie I updated my answer, do not hesitate if you have any questions.

Comment: Omg I understand now and it worked, seriously thank you so much!!